# set static Network settings, enable a wifi adapter

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, redundancy

Here is my scenario,

I have a computer with a LAN Connection and a WiFi Connection, running Windows XP Pro.

I have a local network router (WRVS4400Nv2 from Cisco) with Wireless access and a separate Mobile Hotspot.  Both have internet access.  Primarily we use the Offices LAN/wLAN to connect to the internet, but in the event they are down (Fiber cuts, etc), we use the Mobile Hotspot.

I need to be able to connect to the local network for resources (printers) and the mobile hotspot if it is available with the least amount of setup or physical intervention.

I've tried statically assigning an IP and Subnet to the LAN Adapter (No Gateway or DNS), and then using the WiFi Connection to select either the wLAN of the Office or the Mobile Hotspot.  This worked but the Office wLAN would randomly disconnect.  Is there another way I can accomplish this?

I'm open to scripts that enable the WiFi and set static information on the LAN Connection.  or anything else, it just has to be simple for a Computer Illiterate to institute.